# Application crash at 6.0 version device while scanig qrcode using com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1 library in android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

Hello friends i implement application which is scan qr code from my application and si i use com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1 library for that below is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pkg"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'//Add dependency
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
}
```

And i call scan my barcode as below

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(ActivitySubTask.this);
          scanid=mArrayListGetSubLocations.get(i).getSubid();
        Log.d("scanid ",String.valueOf(scanid));
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
        integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
        integrator.setCameraId(0);
        integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
        integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
        integrator.initiateScan();
    }
});
```

Above code working fine in 4.0 to 5.1 version devices but when i test in 6.0 version device it is crash application and below is my error message comes in my Logcat

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method checkSelfPermission(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)I in class Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/pkg.android.rootways.cleaning-1/base.apk)
at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureManager.openCameraWithPermission(CaptureManager.java:233)
at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureManager.onResume(CaptureManager.java:221)
at  com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity.onResume(CaptureActivity.java:42)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6312)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**EDIT**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: take permission for camera in your mainifest:                                           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

Comment: You need to use `Runtime Permission` check this http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Damini Mehra: i added permission for camera but still i m getting same error

Answer (score 0):

I make solution by change in gradle file by making build version 23 from 22

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pkg"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
  }

 dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
 compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
 compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'//Add     dependency
  compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

On android 6 they implemented a new way of getting permissions

You must ask for them on Runtime

check this link: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en